# get the text of a link in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I need to run a php condition to check for the text that's clicked in a tab. I need to check the text value instead of the url as the url is the same, only text is different. Here's what I have so far:

```
<a href="/some-value">Tab 1</a> 
<a href="/some-value">Tab 2</a> 

<?php 
    $a = 'Tab 1'; //How to check for this value?
    $b = 'Tab 2';

    if (strpos($a,'Tab 1') !== false) {
        echo 'Tab 1'; 
    } else { 
        echo 'Tab 2'; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: PHP is executed on server side. Unless you're parsing the whole html by having the output either in a file or in a variable, there is no way to do that. You'd want to use a client-side scripting language, like javascript, to achieve this...

Comment: The text is not submitted to the server, period. You need to use unique URLs for unique content, that's what the web operates on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it will be better to set the text of anchor in the url.

Like this:

```
<a href="/some-value?tab=Tab 1">Tab 1</a> 
<a href="/some-value?tab=Tab 2">Tab 2</a>
```

And then if you want to know which tab clicked just get the tab value

```
$_REQUEST['tab']
```

Comment: Or even better, `/some-value?tab=1`, and compare numerically.